# How can I run container with process.argv in Docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

My app requires that user input 3 parameters after node index.js, for example:
 `node index.js 1 1 1` .

When I used just Dockerfile, I wrote this there:
    `ENTRYPOINT ["node", "index.js"]`
And after I executed in terminal command:
  `docker run  1 1 1`. It's worked, arguments was in process.argv
But now I need to use docker-compose.yml, and I don't know what I must do.

Answer (score 1):

As the values are "static" for a running container and will not change during runtime of the container you could simply use environment variables.

Inside your docker-compose.yml define environment variables (used as default values) for the container like:

```
<service_name>:
  environment:
    - value1: 1
    - value2: 1
    - value3: 1
```

Refer to: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Change the entrypoint to use the environment variables like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "index.js", "$value1", "$value2", "$value3"]
```

When you start the container you can simply change the values with:

```
docker-compose run -e value1=2
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.